# Error on ngFor only show the second object from array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

There should be two editable input field for each section, and each section should have it's corresponding data. However, it end's up that only the second JSON from sample was display in both section.

The JSON in the TS file look Like this:

```
this.sample = [
{
"sectionone":"abc",
"sectiontwo":"dec"
},
{
"sectionone":"ncs",
"sectiontwo":"sec"
}];
```

the html file

```
<div ngFor="let x in sample; let i = index">
 <h6>{{i}}</h6>
 <h6>{{sample[i].sectionone}}</h6>
  <div class="A">
  <label>Section ONE</label>
    <div class="one {i}" >
     <input [(ngModel)] = "sample[i].sectionone" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="A">
  <label>Section TWO</label>
    <div class="two {i}" >
     <input [(ngModel)] = "sample[i].sectiontwo" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
</div>
```

so the result for h6 , I am getting 0 abc, and 1 ncs, which is the correct answer I need, however, the data display in the input section are section one: ncs, section two: sec, section one: ncs, section two: sec. Both are using the second JSON from the sample Array. I have no idea where it went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

hello you made just some small mistake ,
here is the correction

```
<div *ngFor="let x of sample; let i = index ">
    <h6>{{i}}</h6>
    <h6>{{x.sectionone}}</h6>
    <div class="A">
        <label>Section ONE</label>
        <div class="one {i}">
            <input [(ngModel)] = "x.sectionone" />
    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="A">
            <label>Section TWO</label>
            <div class="two {i}">
                <input [(ngModel)] = "x.sectiontwo" />
    </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
</div>
```

the syntax of `*ngFor` was wrong , the correct one is with **of** and not **in**.
You can use the `let x` instead of the array and the index.
here is the [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iminyk?file=src/app/app.component.html)